# python: finding the intersection of two gaussian_kde functions (objects)

Tags: python, probability, gaussian

I have two python gaussian_kde objects and I'd like to find the intersection. 
Is there a simple way to do it?

Note that the functions are not nicely parametrized, see figure. [image]

Here is a naive way to do it (assuming that there is only one intersection, but it could be easily modified for all intersections in the scope, given that there are no more than one intersection in the specified init_interval):

```
def find_intersection(kde1, kde2, init_interval=0.01, scope =[0,1], convergence=0.0001):
x_left = scope[0]
x_right = scope[0]+init_interval
while x_right < scope[1]:
    left = kde1(x_left)[0]-kde2(x_left)[0]
    right = kde1(x_right)[0]-kde2(x_right)[0]
    if left*right < 0: #meaning the functions intersected (an odd number of times) in the interval
        if init_interval <= convergence:
            return x_right
        else: 
            return find_intersection(kde1, kde2, init_interval/10, scope=[x_left, x_right])
    else: #no intersection or an even number of intersections in the interval
        x_left = x_right
        x_right+=init_interval
return scope[0]-1 #out of scope means no intersection
```

For the KDEs of the plots we get:

```
>>>from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
>>>data1 = d_sp.values()
>>>density1 = gaussian_kde(data1)
>>>data2 = d_xp.values()
>>>density2 = gaussian_kde(data2)
>>>xs = np.linspace(0,.2,200)
>>>print find_intersection(density1, density2) 
0.0403   
>>>print find_intersection(density1, density2, convergence=0.000001)
0.0403
```

I'm wondering if there is a "closed form" exploiting the KDE function and object that could give the right solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post some code? With which data structures are you working with? How are data disposed?

Comment: I can't post the data/code right now - I'll try doing it later. But the question is about using the gaussian_kde objects (imagine no data is given - only these estimates). One way of doing it is by hill-climbing but this is pretty ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to help if there is no code, but i implemented a full example consisting of:

- data-generation including random-sampling
- kde-fitting
- intersection-finding

#### Approach

The basic idea is to use some general root-finding algorithm. For this purpose we are using [brentq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html#scipy.optimize.brentq) from scipy.

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.optimize import brentq
from sklearn.neighbors.kde import KernelDensity

# Generate normal functions
x_axis = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
gaussianA = norm.pdf(x_axis, 2, 0.5)  # mean, sigma
gaussianB = norm.pdf(x_axis, 0.1, 1.5)

# Random-sampling from functions
a_samples = norm.rvs(2, 0.5, size=100)
b_samples = norm.rvs(0.1, 1.5, size=100)

# Fit KDE
def kde_sklearn(x, x_grid, bandwidth=0.2, **kwargs):
    """Kernel Density Estimation with Scikit-learn"""
    kde_skl = KernelDensity(bandwidth=bandwidth, **kwargs)
    kde_skl.fit(x[:, np.newaxis])
    # score_samples() returns the log-likelihood of the samples
    log_pdf = kde_skl.score_samples(x_grid[:, np.newaxis])
    return kde_skl, np.exp(log_pdf)

kdeA, pdfA = kde_sklearn(a_samples, x_axis, bandwidth=0.25)
kdeB, pdfB = kde_sklearn(b_samples, x_axis, bandwidth=0.25)

# Find intersection
def findIntersection(fun1, fun2, lower, upper):
    return brentq(lambda x : fun1(x) - fun2(x), lower, upper)

funcA = lambda x: np.exp(kdeA.score_samples([[x]][0]))
funcB = lambda x: np.exp(kdeB.score_samples([[x]][0]))

result = findIntersection(funcA, funcB, -3, 3)

# Plot
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(x_axis, gaussianA, color='green')
ax1.plot(x_axis, gaussianB, color='blue')
ax1.set_title('Original Gaussians')
ax2.plot(x_axis, pdfA, color='green')
ax2.plot(x_axis, pdfB, color='blue')
ax2.set_title('KDEs of subsampled Gaussians')
ax2.axvline(result, color='red')
plt.show()
```

#### Output

[image: Output]

#### Remarks

- brentq seems to be the most common root-finding algorithm (because it's stable and fast) but depending on your data, parameter-tuning could be needed
- it's possible to switch to some [other](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/optimize.html) optimization algorithm
- (there are some simplifications for modelling purposes; e.g. normally kde-bandwith selection should be done with cross-validation to obtain something 
  better than the ones in my example)

**EDIT: switched from fsolve to brentq, which should be faster & more stable**

Comment: Thanks! Beautiful answer. Btw, on my data, your code gives 0.0402106805 and my code (with convergence=0.000000001) is 0.0402106806 :)

Comment: But - with your solution you need to specify the bound carefully. For example, if the upper>=0.5 (using my data) the intersection is found to be the upper bound (both functions are 0 from about x=0.14). I guess it's due to the bisectioning but I'm not sure.

Comment: I also compared timing: in order to get the same result I need to use convergence=0.000000001 and your method runs 5 times faster. But if I settle for lower accuracy (say 0.0403) running times are comparable.

Comment: You could also tune brentq to optimize for lower accuracy which should take less iterations. xtol and rtol are the parameters. Regarding the bounds: this could be really tricky depending on the environment, because they need to be sign-changing. Most of the time one could overshoot (be generous) and it works. One more remark about KDEs: in general i prefer the versions in sklearn / statsmodels, because of cross-validation support for bandwith-params. sklearn (which was my favourite earlier) can use GridSearch/RandomSearch, statsmodels (which is my fav now) can use opt-based CV.

Comment: thanks. I'm new to this side of scipy. I wonder if my ad hoc solution is slower   because it's pure python (and using a while loop and recursion) instead of the scipy functions that are implemented with C/++.

Comment: Oh the difference is huge! brentq is very complex (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method)). It uses interpolation to speed up search (like estimating gradients using some smoothness assumptions). So the difference is about algorithmics, not Python vs. C++.

Comment: (my comment was cut) Essentially, my method finds a scope containing an intersection then zooms in. Obviously that's less principled than defining a new function then finding the 0-derivative or the roots. But if I understand correctly (?!) brentq wouldn't provide a fixed form but also involves iterations till convergence.

Comment: Yes. It's an iterative algorithm which eventually will converge. It's a general algorithm supporting non-linear functions, so no fixed-form information is used (but interpolation is calculated for speedup)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not going to write code, but I've thought about some idea

From gaussian KDe estimate for PDF you could get estimate for CDF, and that would be no-accuracy-loss step, from weighted sum of gaussians to the weighted sum of error functions.

So you have CDF1(x) and CDF2(x). You build f(x)=CDF1(x)-CDF2(x). It is equal to
0 at xmin and to 0 at xmax. If we're to find min/max of the f(x), we should compute the derivative of the f(x) and check where such derivative is equal to 0.

So, f'(x)=(CDF1(x)-CDF2(x))' = PDF1(x) - PDF2(x), and guess what - it would be equal to 0 at exactly PDFs intersection point. Thus we could convert search-for-intersection problem to the search-for-min/max problem.

So I would propose to build f(x) and pass it down to some min/max finding routine, say, `fmin()`, or `minimize_scalar` from scipy.optimize.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The idea is similar to @sascha's.

Comment: @ScienceFriction no, it is not. He formulated (and solved) problem of the root finding for a particular function. I proposed to look at the problem as minimum/maximum search of the related function